# what's the difference between send email with "deliver" and without "deliver"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the difference between following two email invoke approach? One with deliver while another not.

```
mail(:to => 'test@gmail.com', :subject => "Test") do |format|
    format.html { render layout: false }
end.deliver

mail(:to => 'test@gmail.com', :subject => "Test") do |format|
    format.html { render layout: false }
end
```

Comment: only .deliver will deliver email .....

Answer (score 2):

`.deliver` actually send message, block without `.deliver` just create mail object but not send it. `.deliver` is operation for sending email like `.deliver_later` or custom created delivery method (example: you generate mail using method without `.deliver` and then your cron_job send this emails later).

You can find more information here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#walkthrough-to-generating-a-mailer

or

good example working with emails:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email-revised?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell... just the flat `mail` function will send the email. If you construct a `Mail::Message` object, you need to call `.deliver` on it to get it to send, but the `mail` function seems to do that for you.

(At least, as far as I can tell. I have yet to test it, so I'm not sure)